# Getting "semi" orthogonal basis from a linear independent set

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, orthonormal

Let $K_i: \mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}^k$ are continuous functions for all $i=1,\dots,k-d$ such that for every fixed $t\in\mathbb{R}$ we have ${\cal K}_t=\{K_1(t),\dots,K_{k-d}(t)\}$ be a linear independent set in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

I'd like to have $d-$vector functions $B_1(),\dots,B_d()$ such that $B_i$ are continuous, $B_i(t)\bot K_j(t)$ for all $t$, for every  $i=1,\dots,d$ and $j=1,\dots,k-d$, and also
\begin{equation}
{\cal K}_t\cup\{B_1(t),\dots,B_d(t)\}
\end{equation} 
is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^k$.

To do this, note that from the standard basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_k\}$, we can choose $d-$vectors of them called by $f_1,\dots,f_d$ such that ${\cal K}_t\cup\{f_1,\dots,f_d\}$ is basis. But, how can we make they are orthogonal with $\cal K_t$. As I know, the gram schmidt produces an orthogonal basis, but I need to have partly orthogonal by fixing the $(k-d)-$vectors in my basis. Any suggestion? Thanks for any help.

Comment: See variation on this problem, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688292/partly-orthogonal-of-a-basis

Comment: If the $K_i$ are functions, and not real numbers, then we are not talking about sets in ${\bf R}^k$. And you have to tell us what it means for one function to be orthogonal to another.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson. So, in my case above, how will I take my problem?

Comment: I don't know. The problem is a mess. You have to make up your mind whether these things are numbers (in which case, we are just back to your earlier problem, already solved), or functions (in which case you have to say what you mean by orthogonal, but in any event you won't have a finite basis for a space of continuous functions).

Comment: I've edited my sentence. It might not be confusing now.

Comment: It's still a mess. You want, for all $t$, that the numbers $B_i(t)$ and $K_j(t)$ be orthogonal --- what does it mean for two real numbers to be orthogonal? You write of choosing constant vectors $f_i$ to form a basis with the $K_i(t)$ --- presumably for all $t$ --- but there's no reason to think that's possible.

Comment: $B_i$ and $K_j$ are vectors defined as a function of $t$. So, it makes sense. Doesn't it?

Comment: You define $K_i$ to be a continuous function on the reals. I assumed that each $K_i$ is a function from the reals to the reals. Are you saying that each $K_i$ is a function from the reals to ${\bf R}^k$?

Comment: Yes @Gerry. That is What I meant. Any idea?

Comment: I have editted for this point

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/158844/extending-continuous-basis

Comment: Wait, this is actually the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683356/extended-matrix-function isn't it? How many different times have you posted this same question here?

Comment: It's not actually the same as given link. This version is simpler

Comment: Fair enough, I only skimmed it. But as a matter of courtesy, when you post closely related questions, you should leave a link to each question at each of the others.

Comment: OK @GerryMyerson. Thanks for your advice